# how to add content controls in word document using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

I want to add content controls in my word document so that if someone update them in word it automatically update in whole document where ever it is used. for example, I want date on first page of document as comments content control which also i want to use in header. so that if i open document and change the date in first page it automatically change in header also.
like in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2stWH.png)

Comment: Why using Python? If you put the date in its own custom style, you can use a StyleRef field in your headers.https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF The same thing works with other information like the addressee's name and subject. See my tutorial https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#LetterheadTextboxesAndStylesTutorial. If you want a Content Control, you need a Mapped Content Control to do what you want. See http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.